# No "ls" command in bash for Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have recently installed `bash` in Windows 10.

Everything seems to be working fine, with the exception of the "`ls`" command. When I type `ls` from the `$` prompt, it returns nothing and goes directly back to my `$` prompt.

Am I doing something wrong, or do I need to enable `ls` somewhere? I am new to Linux and trying to learn everything that I can. I just can't figure this one out.

Comment: It probably returns nothing because there is nothing there. (Note that, by default, `ls` does not show hidden files, i.e. files starting with a `.`. Use `ls -a` instead to show those.)

Comment: Also note that "no result" is very different from "missing command" — trying to run a missing command will give you a very obvious error, e.g. `No command 'ls' found`

Comment: Thanks Bob, That worked. I guess I assumed that there would be something there. But I guess being my home folder, and I just installed, there is nothing there. Another quick question. Should lsusb show my usb connections? Or am I not clear on the syntax for this command?  Thanks again. Sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: I suspect `lsusb` won't work because WSL doesn't have full USB device support yet. Keep in mind that WSL runs a Linux-like (usually Ubuntu) userspace on the Windows kernel but isn't *actually* Linux - and we're still a while away from full compatibility. For the most part, this means a lot of the functionality that requires direct hardware access isn't there yet. If you want to play around with a real Linux installation, I would suggest installing, say, Ubuntu in a virtual machine (e.g. VirtualBox).

Comment: Bob, Ill do that. Thanks again for your timely response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably returns nothing because there is nothing there. You are probably in your user's home directory, which contains no normal files in a new install.

Note that, by default, `ls` does not show hidden files, i.e. files starting with a `.`. Use `ls -a` instead to show those.

If you create a file, e.g. with `touch filename`, it should show up with a normal `ls`. Alternatively, if you `ls /` (list files in the root dir) there will almost certainly be something there.

Also note that "no result" is very different from "missing command" — trying to run a missing command will give you a very obvious error, e.g. `No command 'ls' found`